# Typescript Conditional Return Type Problem

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I am trying to use a conditional return type for a function to either return a string or a tuple, depending on the value of an option passed as an argument. For some reason, the Typescript compiler is complaining.

```js
function fetchFromDB() {
  return 'Apple';
}

function fetchRelatedFromDB() {
  return ['Banana', 'Cherry'];
}

type Options = {
  includeRelated?: boolean;
};

type ConditionalReturn<T extends Options> = T extends {
  includeRelated: true;
}
  ? [string, string[]]
  : string;

export function find<T extends Options>(
  options: T
): ConditionalReturn<T> {
  const fruit = fetchFromDB();

  if (options.includeRelated) {
    const related = fetchRelatedFromDB();
    return [fruit, related];
  }

  return fruit;
}

const stringResult = find({});

const tupleResult = find({ includeRelated: true });
```

See the following playground example...

[Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAplCALAYgJzgWwBEAhACgEpEBvAKEURzRByQHIBBAB04BsVWA3DQC%20NGqEiwEyNJgBKKHgEMoKACa4CJCtToMmLRAG1WxJWHNLWAGkSsAwhhQ4cAT1YBdIaJpRXnFEQAeU4pMABnRABeXXoYSB4QNRQFZVU1AH4ALkQAIzg4PnNvIV9-QPsENRgwpR4FKGYwAB4AFUQUAA9VMDVIkLDwgD5oxHaunr7YxHiIROTUlXUcqBwQFG89DONw1fiAc1tdnAOjDw89HOOD0q7OOBwoZHBoeCRgeLU2ju6UXv7Qm9hqQ9HBAQhwjlWjRyDlKr0am86g0mm0RrR6BAIU9gGsaqNUOhsHgiGRyKU4sBEKQwYMAHSzeYpRRLNSUDH0RBYiJPRhpdQE2QYRbpTSkihCTn6RqGIy4kA1Wx81lePQ%20eiMGXvPFQTY0bm7RDXMD7BThEA8J4xD69UhUYTksQGp6NXjM82WgmfO0zBJJZn8tQrNaBB1CIA)

Line 26 and 29 both show an error. I have used conditional return types before, but this example is stumping me. I appreciate any help.

Here is an example of where I did get conditional return types working.

[Working Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgLzgXzgMyhEcDkyEAJvgNwBQoksiWOIAWiQKJQ5Tr24FHEC0ANwCGAG2DFhMYBAB2-AKbto5KuGjwkAZwCOorth75iUYMmSiF-aCFXUNiCnDgAjURADGAawAqATzAFAGUPAAsFEGEAGic4ABkFYShZYFkAcwAFKVCAIXdvGOcAMWgPBQBZAFdRaTBxJTzPL0K4IK9gUVFGgtiAYQhKqC0FbubYuOEXUZaQm2nYgEEtYeWQBVkYeecWAA9hEC24AEVKs0PykmqR-LHnLLTrppaANXXiaCWVrTWNw9fZd5QfqDYajCgYQx4fAAOgA9FowhFhNCAFZaOzqWhISQwSbCYZRVw3LQ%20SaWAwMAhwnF44ao9GUexYuAPTY3fyBLQUoxw1n8NxNfgwAIKLT01QUDxyLTwYguOAAXjgNJc%20IUAAoAJSUSXS%20AI8KRRUoaEQFwohQeGDqhCxYWBABcRKaHOCiMiLWkMEsTuQ0JlpnSWtNYGkcjEWpaYGyvv9MEDaWDSSgwj8wYgoZksgjmvB2ooFHtCjgvSgiRgCgA8pnpca-alMEoADxFiCYOAGpEAPh1RZLcmIwDD2dEACUFDBBrImz44AodhWAVzS%20WqzXZFou8bZ-PF8QubbnEWnfhLEkUul%20NGYKFVGhYgB%20eKJZKpTLZMHOJ07hdvA9wY8CEwUorBAapanqKB8HQWJnCfEooDKKoamAOpgAaG5YLgb851-Jc6EA-AtHaTpoPvZwKLgJ82g6LpMMor84B-Pd-0IqUQQUMisMop9gSGR5vG4iicN3P8CJFE9REmLiGIYp8JimejZOEpjcJY8THQIBEbBk5SeNaKUoAOJS9MY5ixKQQj8S%20H4YF00yKKfT5RW%20dY2SaIS9JEvD9w0hQT3nfZ7Icxy4F2fZPxCyjvPUyyJIIHRTmQYKorg44ksi1KVPM-C4s0-AQEuSwUqyqi4AuYgrky0qzLUiyAPi-BoweEqaqfe4BK8TzSpi%20rCMEN5oH4ayXNs1qarK-5AWc1Y3Oqibsrq3KGvygaASG9j%20PGhanym6A%20NBEyFoYp1ZAUAaoB1ecaFlBRMGEcC4HxPxZA8LBKle4c4A8MspAUGclt8lc-urYdN3VWIMzB78KE1J0MgYYBhibfoASHLMxHHSdkhnLst0PACoD8RxKKlDd4GjfjiGNTtImhSnhnVKGsy0fMsLJmVnW8Y1hAAd2EIdlRcaF42EDdhCtLN1We16AJ2RV8aEjn4DLLRHqVPmBfgGAdm66FUmGWB1QFbwSTJBRcz06ERFESpRRtbqj3ihmFGIEWRRaPSvR9OAXbd73iwfJ98AAVQ2IdLFIbq0Et5ToTLbGL0TNnZOVuADaUCtqaVVXwIAbQABgAXR1WTgHbdU-fp7I4AAMlr32kmGN3r1CaFLHSG84C3AvNRJ5S07Edx%20bcBRelCDoTHWHn%20cF1lRldLQbUbm8nSr1v0BT5Ty7gdUAEIh4gEfLHHyey1kfXXtt4h7arotNVjr3QhwXm4DO1%202A4CGooAA1GFbiwABIEB3xFBgJGb8IDwEPrzV2T1tbhA7IEDw5d0LU1btCH%20js4Bb1TnqRu58YAAEls4EObtXG8ed17ZHbusNIXd%20BwAAIwlwLHpTWgsdbQnnJaSoFZv6mV0KIH%20IcMgABEFg%20BYFzLwXIggsFnGEM%2008NbsFTAAfWEGAQIAJ1RKNEFPWQhJgEZ1gK7fWxAY5wAAOoAAkWCjmkRIY0wDKZuRIWgLBel8yyXvEJBOU504bkzq7SglEY6lwogE5IMinpcjFn4MJXAPBSDCLvJQUA%204E2cDvdUGSgkyjFmUNsJpmDEE-tAPuN4X7cCYKwZQUA8nsB8RRapR85zsCSfee8QA)

Comment: "I have used conditional return types before" But such error are the rule, not the exception. See [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912). Can you explain how you used them before and how it managed to work?  Generally you have to just use type assertions or something similar (as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w1GkOm)), at least until ms/TS#33912 is implemented. I could write up an answer saying as much, but your mention of previous experience with conditional return types gives me pause. How should we proceed here?

Comment: @jcalz I put a working example link in the original post.

Comment: Your working example has `return block as any`; [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) is explicitly a "don't type check this" marker, and so the whole implementation returns `any`, and so the conditional return type is automatically satisfied by it.  Type assertions, the `any` type, or other type loosening is the only way to proceed currently with generic conditional return types. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up my answer; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's your desired output, but you could use a "strange" way to achieve this through type assertion forcing the generic type for each return output as follows

```js
export function find<T extends Options>(options: T): ConditionalReturn<T> {
  const fruit = fetchFromDB();

  if (options.includeRelated) {
    const related = fetchRelatedFromDB();
    return <ConditionalReturn<T>>[fruit, related];
  }

  return <ConditionalReturn<T>>fruit;
}
```

Comment: This isn't a "strange" way, per se. Using type assertions (as mentioned in [my above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78084719/typescript-conditional-return-type-problem/78093862#comment137658712_78084719)) is one of the "standard" ways to deal with generic conditional return types. There's more to be said on this topic, though, especially in light of some features in the roadmap for TS5.5 which might make this possible without type assertions.

Comment: @jcalz yeah, it's strange because you expect that typescript should infer it without explicit type assertion